# SQL query error in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

I tried the code below in phpmyadmin, but received a syntax error:

```
select * from `reviews_az` 
left join `restaurants_az` on `reviews_az`.`restaurant_id` = `restaurants_az`.`id`  
where `source` LIKE %YELP% order by `reviews_az`.`id` desc limit 6);
```

This is the error log:

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%YELP% order by `reviews_az`.`id` desc limit 6)' at line 1

Comment: Use `LIKE '%YELP%'`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing single quote in like.

Correct query:

`select * from reviews_az left join restaurants_az on reviews_az.restaurant_id = restaurants_az.id where source LIKE '%YELP%' order by reviews_az.id desc limit 6`

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. Missing quotes in LIKE.

**Change**

```
LIKE '%YELP%'
```

**Query**

```
select * from `reviews_az` 
left join `restaurants_az` on `reviews_az`.`restaurant_id` = `restaurants_az`.`id`  
where `source` LIKE '%YELP%' order by `reviews_az`.`id` desc limit 6;
```

Comment: And the extra `)`?

Comment: Accept the answer with right click on answer if its useful to you. :) @Trishna